# How to maintain state of selected records after search in Lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, search, checkbox

I'm not able to maintain the checkbox state, when lightning:datatable records change after searching records in the datatable.
I have a searchbar above the Lightning datatable and records with checkbox. After a click on the checkbox I am printing the records below the datatable, and when the checkbox is deselected, the associated printed record should be deleted, and this is what happens before a search. But after a search the preselected records go into unselected state.

Please help me to maintain the preselected records after search.

```html
    <!---Datatable--->
    <lightning:datatable
        keyField="SysId"
        columns="{!v.columnsCopy }"
        data="{!v.data}"
        hideCheckBoxColumn="true"
        defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection}"
        sortedDirection="{!v.sortDirection}"
        sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
        onsort="{!c.handleSort}"
        onrowselection="{!c.handleSelect}"
        selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}">
    </lightning:datatable>
```

```javascript
    <!--controller method-->
    
    handleSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
                var setRows = component.get('v.selectedUsers');
    
                selectedRows.forEach(function(element, index) {
            
                    if (!setRows.find(({
                            SysId
                        }) => SysId === element.SysId)) {
                        setRows.push(element);
                    }
                });
                console.log('selectedRows2 ' + JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
                for (var i = 0; i < setRows.length; i++) {
                    var isPresent = false;
                    for (var j = 0; j < selectedRows.length; j++) {
                        if (selectedRows[j].SysId === setRows[i].SysId) {
                            isPresent = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isPresent) {
                        setRows.splice(i, 1);
            
                    }
                }
                component.set("v.selectedUsers", setRows);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
handleRowSelection(event) {
       
        //this.selectedPricebookEntries = event.detail.selectedRows;
        let allSelectedRowsSet = new Set(this.selectedRows); //all selected
        let currentSelectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows; //currently selected
        let currentSelectedRowsSet = new Set();
        let selectedRowsUpdated = !this.arrayCompare(currentSelectedRows, this.selectedPricebookEntries);

        if(selectedRowsUpdated) {
            if(currentSelectedRows) {
                currentSelectedRows.map((pricebookEntry) => {
                    currentSelectedRowsSet.add(pricebookEntry.Id);
                });
                
                currentSelectedRowsSet.forEach((pricebookEntryId) => {
                    //add currently selected to all selected if it is not there yet
                    if(!allSelectedRowsSet.has(pricebookEntryId)) {
                        allSelectedRowsSet.add(pricebookEntryId);
                    }
                });
            }

            let allPricebookEntries = this.PricebookEntriesData; //all data
            if(allPricebookEntries) {
                allPricebookEntries.forEach((pricebookEntry) => {
                    if (allSelectedRowsSet.has(pricebookEntry.Id) && !currentSelectedRowsSet.has(pricebookEntry.Id)) {
                        // Remove any items that were unselected.
                        allSelectedRowsSet.delete(pricebookEntry.Id);
                    }
                });
            }
            
            if(allSelectedRowsSet.size > 0) {
                let selected = allPricebookEntries.filter(pb => allSelectedRowsSet.has(pb.Id));
                let others = allPricebookEntries.filter(pb => !allSelectedRowsSet.has(pb.Id));
                //set selected pricebook entries
                this.selectedPricebookEntries = selected;
                this.selectedRows = [...selected];
                //push selected items at the start of the table
                this.PricebookEntriesData = [...selected, ...others];
            }
        }

        //console.log('~ CustomAddProductsModal -> handleRowSelection -> this.selectedPricebookEntries: ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedPricebookEntries));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for your contribution. Here on SFSE the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code) in an answer - especially since it can help future searchers/readers. Please [edit]https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/388785/edit) your answer to explain - even briefly (but enough to understand) - what in your code is different from the code posted in the question, and why that solves the problem.